# How to return null in map?

Tags: c++

I am trying to return null if the `accountNo` wasn't find the the `map`.
But I have only used linkedlist in the past in java.
I have no idea how to return something else in c++ map.

```
113 Account Bank::BalanceEnquiry(long accountNo){
114         map<long, Account>::iterator itr = accounts.find(accountNo);
115         return itr->second;
116 }
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional), which is a wrapper that may or may not contain a value:

```
std::optional<Account> Bank::BalanceEnquiry(long accountNo){
    auto itr = accounts.find(accountNo);
    
    if(itr == accounts.end()) {
        return std::nullopt; // empty value, that's like null from Java
    }

    return std::optional<Account>{itr->second}; // return non-empty value
}
```

It can be used like this (with a `Bank`-object `myBank`):

```
std::optional<Account> balanceEnquiry = myBank.BalanceEnquiry(someValue);

if(balanceEnquiry) {
    // entry found, we can extract the actual value

    Account foundAccount = balanceEnquiry.value();
}
else {
    // entry not found
}
```

Comment: It's give me error that ```no template named "optional" ```. Do I need to create template?

Comment: `@realNameDoesn'tExist` did you add the header optional?; `#include <optional>;`

Comment: I did add that. but I don't add **std::** since I am using **using namespace std;**

Comment: @realNameDoesn'tExist *I am using using namespace std;* -- Don't use it, and especially if you're using it in a header file.

Comment: `std::optional c++17` feature; what version are you compiling with?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie if I don't use **using namespace std;** , I have to add all a lot of **std:** in some cases.

Comment: I am using c++11 @pvc

Comment: At the very least, remove `using namespace std;` from any header file you have now.   If you have to type in `std::` for the things in the header, so be it.  You should never have `using namespace std` in a header file.

Comment: if you need `c++11` option, see below answer from `@Slava`, returning pointer, will work for you.

Comment: I don't know why I am getting this in the usage ```main.cpp:203:7: note: jump bypasses variable initialization
        auto acc = b.BalanceEnquiry(accountNo);
             ^
``` I did switch the compiler to c++17 @pvc

Comment: @realNameDoesn'tExist Do you use `goto`? If yes,  the compiler is telling you, that there is a `goto` that skips the line where `auto acc` is initialized, which could cause UB.

Answer (score 6):

Unlike Java in C++ you can return object by value (or by reference) or by pointer. If you are returning by value (as in your code) you cannot return `nullptr` unless your `class` `Account` has special state. So you have to change return type. Possible variants:

```
// return a pointer
Account *Bank::BalanceEnquiry(long accountNo){
      auto itr = accounts.find(accountNo);
      return itr == accounts.end() ? nullptr : &(itr->second);
}
// usage
auto account = bank.BalanceEnquiry(123);
if( account ) account->do_something();

// return std::optional
std::optional<Account> Bank::BalanceEnquiry(long accountNo){
      auto itr = accounts.find(accountNo);
      return itr == accounts.end() ? std::optional<Account>() : itr->second;
}
// usage
auto account = bank.BalanceEnquiry(123);
if( account ) account.value().do_something();
```